# Laptop is super slow on network

Tags: windows-7, performance, internet

So on our network we have a bunch of wireless macs and window Operating laptops, we have a network setup with 802.11g,b,n. All the laptops seem fine except one which is only getting speeds of 54Mb. I have changed the encryption from AES to TKIP and reset the connection, i have updated the drivers, tried plugging it into the LAN and still same slow speed. Apparently the laptop with the slow speed is fine on other networks.

I don't know what to do, can anyone help me?